# how to escape parenthesis in ls commands

Tags: bash, ls

I do not succed to filter with ls files with parenthesis (on bash)

```
$ ls -1
a_échéancier(1).pdf
a_échéancier(2).pdf
a_échéancier(3).pdf
a_échéancier(4).pdf
a_échéancier(5).pdf
a_échéancier(6).pdf
a_échéancier.pdf
$
```

A try here:

```
$ ls "*).pdf"
ls: cannot access '*).pdf': No such file or directory
$
$ ls '*\).pdf'
ls: cannot access '*\).pdf': No such file or directory
$
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with ls and everything with the shell you're using.

Comment: What shell? Bash? Csh? ... You need to tag the shell you ate using. Tagging `ls` isn't useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are escaping too many characters; the only character that needs to be escaped is `)`:

```
ls *\).pdf
```

but everything else except the `*` *can* be escaped:

```
ls *").pdf"
```

The shell itself is what expands the glob before `ls` even runs; `ls` just gets an explicit list of filenames. Quoting the `*` makes `ls` try to list the single file named `*).pdf`, not every file in the current directory that matches the pattern.

Answer (score -3):

`ls -1 | grep "*).pdf"` should do the job. `ls` with a filename after it just tries to match it exactly.